# How to set the line spacing for text in richtextbox in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

When I use richtextbox for text editing, there is a huge line spacing, but when I open the same text/file in FlowDocument it looks perfectly fine. Is there a simple way to change the line spacing in richtextbox as well to match with that of the FlowDocument?

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Inlines.Add(dataContent);

FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
selectedRTB.Document = document;
selectedTabItem.Content = selectedRTB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <RichTextBox >
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph LineHeight="50">
                Paragraph1
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph LineHeight="20">
                Paragraph2
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument >
    </RichTextBox>
```

have a try.

Comment: http://www.allinsight.de/wpf-richtextbox-how-to-change-the-paragraph-spacing-add-a-single-row-on-enter/ This solves my problem, but I add richtextbox dynamically, so how do I solve the problem in code rather than in XAML?

Comment: `Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

            p.LineHeight = 50;

            FlowDocument fd = new  FlowDocument(p);

            rtbShow.Document = fd;`